# QPushButton icon aligned left with text centered

Tags: qt, alignment, leftalign

In my Qt 5.7.1 application I've some buttons, I want to align button's icons to left and centre text, but there is no option in designer to do this.

[image: Standard algin]

I can align icon and text left by adding to button stylesheet this code:

> text-align:left;

[image: Align left]

But it's not what I want to achieve.
So, could you please tell me, If there is any option to align icon to left, and keep text aligned center? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply specialize `QPushButton` and override `paintEvent` and `sizeHint`, as proposed by cbuchart [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43806503/3336423). Then use it as a regular `QPushButton`.

## `MyButton` declaration and implementation:

**mybutton.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <QPushButton>

class MyButton : public QPushButton
{
public:
    explicit MyButton(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~MyButton();

    void setPixmap(const QPixmap& pixmap);

    virtual QSize sizeHint() const override;

protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e) override;

private:
    QPixmap m_pixmap;
};
```

**mybutton.cpp:**

```
#include "mybutton.h"

#include <QPainter>

MyButton::MyButton(QWidget* parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{
}

MyButton::~MyButton()
{
}

QSize MyButton::sizeHint() const
{
    const auto parentHint = QPushButton::sizeHint();
    // add margins here if needed
    return QSize(parentHint.width() + m_pixmap.width(), std::max(parentHint.height(), m_pixmap.height()));
}

void MyButton::setPixmap(const QPixmap& pixmap)
{
    m_pixmap = pixmap;
}

void MyButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
{
    QPushButton::paintEvent(e);

    if (!m_pixmap.isNull())
    {
        const int y = (height() - m_pixmap.height()) / 2; // add margin if needed
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawPixmap(5, y, m_pixmap); // hardcoded horizontal margin
    }
}
```

## Exemple of usage:

Here is an example where "Promote widget" feature in Qt Designer was used to create `MyButton` from .ui files:

**mainframe.ui:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="MyButton" name="button1">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Button</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="MyButton" name="button2">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Other button</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>MyButton</class>
   <extends>QPushButton</extends>
   <header>mybutton.h</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**mainwindow.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QStyle>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QStyle* style = qApp->style();
    // set buttons pixmaps:
    ui->button1->setPixmap( style->standardPixmap(QStyle::SP_ComputerIcon) );
    ui->button2->setPixmap( style->standardPixmap(QStyle::SP_TrashIcon) );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Results in:

[image]

- Compared to docsteer answer, this solution makes it possible to apply the new style to only some buttons of your project. And the code is also smaller.
- Compared to IGHOR answer, you can still use the button as a regular `QPushButton` (using `QPushButton::setText`), you don't need to keep a reference to a mockup `QLabel` to change button's text.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to implement this, but after promoting widget, nothing change :( How should I implement this?

Comment: Have you called setPixmap? Is paintEvent called (try to put a breakpoint here)

Comment: @km2442: Added an example of usage through a .ui

Comment: will check this out toomorow at home :)

Comment: Ok, It's working well, but icon is pixelised after scalling to proper size... Is there a option to set this pixmap from designer?

Comment: @km2442: Dunno how to do that. Sorry.To avoid pixelation, you may rescale the pixmap using http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled with option `Qt::SmoothTransformation`

Comment: Ok, now it looks good - thanks. One more question, I'm using grid layout, how can I set horizontal margin width? With 25x25 pixmap icon don't fit to button... When I used creator and added big icon, creator automatically adjusted vertical margin :/ http://i.imgur.com/0578ghT.jpg

Comment: @km2442: Just try to extend button height in `MyButton::sizeHint()`

Comment: Done, now it's ok. I have found another problem. I have to resize and move Label inside Button, because now text is not centered, and text is covered by pixmap :/ http://i.imgur.com/jiyMun1.jpg Is there a option to enable word wrap for button?

Comment: @km2442: Word wrap won't know there is an image being displayed...so this won't help. You could try to consider hidding the pixmap if there is not enough space to show it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146180/discussion-between-km2442-and-jpo38).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Your solution is the best. It doesnt break entire stylesheet and can be applied for selected PushButtins :)

Answer (score 12):

Less code way without breaking UI style

```
pushButton->setIcon(QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxQuestion));
pushButton->setStyleSheet("text-align:left;");
pushButton->setLayout(new QGridLayout);

QLabel* textLabel = new QLabel("Hello world!");
textLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter); // or center
textLabel->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, true);

pushButton->layout()->addWidget(textLabel);
```

Remember to send setText signals to textLabel instead of pushButton

Comment: This is a very interesting workaround. I like how this can be easily translated by `pyQt5` users too. The accepted answer is a bit tougher to read when you're not a C coder, even though there is only really `mybutton.cpp` to translate.

Answer (score 10):

To get this level of control you will need to write some code to override the style for your platform. This is best done using a [QProxyStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html). In this case we are looking for when the style is asked to draw a CE_PushButtonLabel (the label includes the icon, and they are hard coded in Qt to be aligned together).

You need to implement a [QProxyStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html) and override the [drawControl()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html#drawControl) method. The code for the bulk of it is copied directly from the Qt source code for the default drawcontrol method (in [qcommonstyle.cpp](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp?h=5.9.0#n1253)) - so although it looks lengthy, it is mostly doing what Qt already does. I put extra /****/ markers around the sections I modified. This won't show up in Qt Designer, but will work at runtime.

Final result (shown on mac, should match platform you're on)

[image: button with text left]

main.cpp:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
a.setStyle(new MyStyle);
...
```

mystyle.h

```
 class MyStyle : public QProxyStyle
 {
 public:

 virtual void drawControl(ControlElement element, const QStyleOption *opt,
               QPainter *p, const QWidget *widget = Q_NULLPTR) const;
 };
```

mystyle.cpp

```
// Copied from Qt source code..
static QWindow *qt_getWindow(const QWidget *widget)
{
    return widget ? widget->window()->windowHandle() : 0;
}

void MyStyle::drawControl(ControlElement element, const QStyleOption *opt, QPainter *p, const QWidget *widget) const
{
    if(element==CE_PushButtonLabel)
    {
        if (const QStyleOptionButton *button = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionButton *>(opt))
        {
                QRect textRect = button->rect;
                uint tf = Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::TextShowMnemonic;
                if (!proxy()->styleHint(SH_UnderlineShortcut, button, widget))
                    tf |= Qt::TextHideMnemonic;

                if (!button->icon.isNull()) {
                    QRect iconRect;
                    QIcon::Mode mode = button->state & State_Enabled ? QIcon::Normal : QIcon::Disabled;
                    if (mode == QIcon::Normal && button->state & State_HasFocus)
                        mode = QIcon::Active;
                    QIcon::State state = QIcon::Off;
                    if (button->state & State_On)
                        state = QIcon::On;

                    QPixmap pixmap = button->icon.pixmap(qt_getWindow(widget), button->iconSize, mode, state);

                    int pixmapWidth = pixmap.width() / pixmap.devicePixelRatio();
                    int pixmapHeight = pixmap.height() / pixmap.devicePixelRatio();
                    int labelWidth = pixmapWidth;
                    int labelHeight = pixmapHeight;
                    int iconSpacing = 4;//### 4 is currently hardcoded in QPushButton::sizeHint()
                    int textWidth = button->fontMetrics.boundingRect(opt->rect, tf, button->text).width();
                    if (!button->text.isEmpty())
                        labelWidth += (textWidth + iconSpacing);

                    /*************************************************************/
                    // Make the icon rectangle always be 10px in from the left edge
                    /*************************************************************/
                    iconRect = QRect(10,
                                     textRect.y() + (textRect.height() - labelHeight) / 2,
                                     pixmapWidth, pixmapHeight);

                    iconRect = visualRect(button->direction, textRect, iconRect);

                    /***********************************/
                    // Always horizontal align the text
                    /***********************************/
                    tf |= Qt::AlignHCenter;


                    if (button->state & (State_On | State_Sunken))
                        iconRect.translate(proxy()->pixelMetric(PM_ButtonShiftHorizontal, opt, widget),
                                           proxy()->pixelMetric(PM_ButtonShiftVertical, opt, widget));
                    p->drawPixmap(iconRect, pixmap);
                } else {
                    tf |= Qt::AlignHCenter;
                }
                if (button->state & (State_On | State_Sunken))
                    textRect.translate(proxy()->pixelMetric(PM_ButtonShiftHorizontal, opt, widget),
                                 proxy()->pixelMetric(PM_ButtonShiftVertical, opt, widget));

                if (button->features & QStyleOptionButton::HasMenu) {
                    int indicatorSize = proxy()->pixelMetric(PM_MenuButtonIndicator, button, widget);
                    if (button->direction == Qt::LeftToRight)
                        textRect = textRect.adjusted(0, 0, -indicatorSize, 0);
                    else
                        textRect = textRect.adjusted(indicatorSize, 0, 0, 0);
                }
                proxy()->drawItemText(p, textRect, tf, button->palette, (button->state & State_Enabled),
                             button->text, QPalette::ButtonText);
            }
            return;
    }

    // For all other controls, draw the default
    QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, opt, p, widget);
}
```