# Position an icon in the QPushButton

Tags: qt, button, icons, alignment

ALL,

The QPushButton class has a member setIcon() which set the icon to be displayed on the button.

However, there is no parameter to set the icon alignment.

Is there a way to set the icon alignment for the QPushButton?

Thank you.

Comment: second result from google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091339/qpushbutton-icon-aligned-left-with-text-centered/44274465

Comment: @Phiber, I actually want an arbitrary alignment based on the flag: `left`, `top`, `right` or `bottom`. I guess one can just do painting based on the flag inside the paintEvent(), right?

Comment: I think you should to look at `drawControl()` by overriding `ProxyStyle`, there, you can find `Qt::Alignement`